# rails migration for matches between 2 teams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, relationship

I'm a beginner working with ruby on rails at the moment, trying to nail down relations between my models `Matches`, `Teams`.

I want my matches to refer to the `Teams` table twice, once for a `homeTeam` and another for `awayTeam`.  I guess my biggest question is, am I declaring relations incorrectly in my models?

At the moment I'm not even able to call the name of a team through a match.

I want to be able to call Team.matches to list all matches a team has, whether listed as homeTeam or awayTeam, and eventually be able to call the home or away matches for a particular team.

I also want to be able to call Match.teams/Match.homeTeam/Match.awayTeam to list the team(s) of a particular match.

Here's what I have so far:

Match migration

```
class CreateMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      t.references :homeTeam
      t.references :awayTeam
    end
  end
end
```

Match model

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :homeTeam, :class_name => 'Team'
    has_one :awayTeam, :class_name => 'Team'
end
```

Team model

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :matches
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hometeam, :class_name => 'Team'
    belongs_to :awayteam, :class_name => 'Team'

 #if you want to select all teams of a match, you can create a method
 def teams
  Team.find(self.hometeam_id, self.awayteam_id)
 end
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: 'hometeam_id'
  has_many :away, class_name: 'Match', foreign_key: 'awayteam_id'
end
```

Comment: Will I be able to incorporate my `Players` table and call the players of a Match.homeTeam/Match.awayTeam using those models, or will I have to find a way to make the Teams belong to Matches as well?  Thinking like 
`Match`
`has_many :teams`
`has_many :players, through: :teams`

Comment: You will be able to call players like this `Match.find(your_match_id).hometeam.players` to find all home team players, provided you have already declare the associations between Player and Team.